# Print invoice when products are deleted

Tags: magento-1.7, product, invoice

I want to print different invoices, which aren't printed out with all data. Like the color. I see the product is deleted from Magento.

Is there any way to fix this?

Edit:

Invoice.phtml:

```
<td><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('color'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('size'); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried following:

1. Created product
2. Created order, invoice
3. Deleted created product
4. Printed PDF invoice.

Product name exist in PDF invoice. Could you tell what exactly disappeared?

**upd.1.**

I'm not sure but I think it's impossible. When magento build invice - it takes data from sales_flat_invoice_item table. This table contain only two fields, related to the product: SKU and name (these fields exists in invoice table). Method getAttributeText($attributeCode) belongs to catalog/product model and the value is getting from there:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
{
....
    public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
    {
        return $this->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
                ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
    }
```

As product doesn't exist anymore - its impossible.

Comment: The color of the product is the first thing that doesn't show up, and all other data of the invoice after the first data missing.

Comment: Maybe you have some customization? Could you attach 2 screenshots? 1 with existing and 1 with non-existing product.

Comment: I have found the problem, in my invoice.phtml file, it refers to the product to retreive the attributes. I have edited my post. Is there any way to retrieve this from the order?